# control PC using alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have got a requirement of controlling PC/Computer using Alexa skill, i.e if I want to open an excel file on PC then if I simply say Alexa, ask openexcel to open excel file then excel file should be opened.

Can someone please guide me on how to proceed on this requirement.

Thanks
Varun

Comment: This is not how you ask questions on Stackoverflow, please review the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Short overview:

- You need a webserver on your local machine to answer Alexa's requests (I'd suggest Python's simplehttpserver)
- Have the handlers on your webserver control Excel or whatever you need to do (that depends a lot on your os, you didn't mention which you use).
- You need an SSL endpoint to your local webserver (the easy solution is to run ngrok, check ngrok.com

Comment: Thanks Josep  for the response. I am using Windows server.